# Facebook: get the email of a page (not user) via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get the email for a *page*, via any of Facebook's APIs?

I know Facebook user emails are very carefully privacy-protected, but pages seem to be different. For instance: if I visit this FB page, even if I'm not logged in to Facebook, the email is still revealed: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Comcept-Communicatie-Marketing/222648667821245?sk=info

It seems that something so public via their interface ought to be exposed in an API somewhere, but I can't find it. Anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no email for a page in the FQL nor in the page graph api object. So via the API is it not shown.   Remember the API is a stripped down version of what you can see via the normal Facebook GUI.

You're best bet is to have the page admin auth your app asking for email permissions.

Comment: That's what I'd seen also; was hoping someone could tell me I hadn't looked closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't get that information even if you ask for manage_pages and email permissions.

I have raised a bug with Facebook and hopefully they'll add it as a feature if enough people vote:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294577810649098